# Python ASCII Error

Tags: python, ascii, currency

I've been having issues with my Python programming where it is giving me this error:

> Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /home/meyer/Documents/Money/money_counter.py on line 29, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

[The forum that it took me to](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html) wasn't helpful either.

```
#Cent Parts
hundred_cent = (raw_input("How many 100¢ do you have?:\n"))
hundred_centone = hundred_cent * 1.00
#======================================================================
```

Comment: What is the actual input you're giving for `hundred_cent`?

Comment: Set your file encoding: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line. `¢` is not an ASCII character.

Comment: The other problem is you need to parse your `raw_input`, so you'll need `float(raw_input(...))`

Comment: @coldspeed Thank you

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ there's no guarantee that `utf-8` is the proper encoding. Getting it wrong is worse than leaving it off altogether.

Comment: @MarkRansom That alternative is to prepend `u` to that string literal, isn't it? That'd probably be better.

Comment: @COLDSPEED But you would still need to change the encoding. You could however write the string as u'..100\u00A2'

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ OP didn't say if it was Python 2 or 3, if it's 3 then there's no `u` required. But it *should* be a Unicode string, yes. Python needs to know the proper encoding of the source to convert the code to the correct Unicode character. It's too bad that Python doesn't choose a sensible default depending on the platform and instead just fails.